# Is there a way to know of what type is the property bound to my DependencyProperty?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I would like to know what is the Type that is bound to the DependencyProperty of my control. Is there a way to know that?

I have a DependencyProperty like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyValue", typeof(double?), typeof(MyControl),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
                                        {
                                            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
                                            DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                                            PropertyChangedCallback = OnMyValueChanged
                                        });

    public double? MyValue
    {
        get { return (double?)GetValue(MyValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyValueProperty, value); }
    }
```

This is a property of my control, and people can use it like:

```
<myNamespace:MyControl MyValue="{Binding THEIRProperty}"/>
```

THEIRProperty can be anything, I would like to know the actual type of THEIRProperty inside my control, is this possible?

I tried checking on the BindingOperations, but I couldn't find anything. I would like to know, for example if they are binding a **double** or a **double?**.

Comment: didnt you get a binding error when THEIRProperty type is other the double? or double ? and why you wanna know this?

Comment: @blindmeis, no you don't get an error. Matter of fact you can bind a Boolean and it works. I want to know, because if they bind a double I want to add a validation to make the input required.

Comment: @Dzyann if you are developing a `UserControl` for others to use, it is *not* your responsibility to validate what users try to bind to your properties... if they bind an invalid type, it won't work and that will be their problem, not yours.

Comment: @Sheridan, the control was built to support double, and now in a rush I need to make it support double? also. I don't want to mess the projects that are using it with double? So if I could add a validator their apps would still work like before.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. Are you needing it in run time or design time? if it is needed in run time why you do not use ValidateValueCallback or CoerceValueCallback and test the value type not the property type?

Comment: @Mojtaba_Sarooghi, I need to know at run time. How could I use CoerceValueCallback if I don't know If they bound a double or a double?. I want to add a "required" validator automatically if they bind double, so the current users of the control don't get messed up by it supporting double?.

Comment: @Dzyann My bad, it does not work I thought about test if value is  null or not.

Comment: @Dzyann - Have you tried the one i posted? Doesn't that works for you?

Comment: @RohitVats Yes, I am working on it. For some reason sometimes the GetBindingExpression returns null, although my property is bound and MyValue property has a value Set, so I am trying to understand why is that happening.

Comment: That's strange. It shouldn't be null in any case if its binded in GUI. Make sure you are checking that at correct method where view has rendered and bindings are established correctly.

Comment: @RohitVats, I was using it in a View for test, and it seems there were some errors there, which caused it to mess up the bindings. I revised all the bindings and it started to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no publicly exposed property on `BindingExpression` which can get you source type but it is stored in private field i.e. `_sourceType` which you can get via reflection:

```
private static void OnMyValueChanged(DependencyObject d, 
                                     DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
   var bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(d, 
                                             MyControl.MyValueProperty);
   Type sourceType = (Type)bindingExpression.GetType()
                         .GetField("_sourceType", BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                             BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(bindingExpression);
   bool isNullableDouble = sourceType == typeof(double?);
   bool isDouble = sourceType == typeof(double);
}
```

---

Also it is stored in private getter property `ConverterSourceType` which can also be used to get the source type:

```
Type sourceType = (Type)bindingExpression.GetType()
                  .GetProperty("ConverterSourceType", BindingFlags.Instance |
                              BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetGetMethod(true)
                             .Invoke(bindingExpression, null);
```

Comment: This worked, although the "_sourceType", throws an exception, because that property is actually from the Base Class. I used the "ConverterSourceType".